# How to invoke SWT toolbar AS_DROP_DOWN button menu programmatically?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

In Eclipse SWT/Jface/RCP application I created dropdown menu tool button by adding IAction of style AS_DROP_DOWN to the ToolBarManager. Pressing down arrow on button invokes my dropdown menu.

I need to invoke the same menu when I press on toolbar button itself. How can I invoke the drop down menu in the IAction.run() or the IAction.runWithEvent(Event) method?

Here is simple code example:

```java
class MyToolbarButtonsCreator {

  public void createButtons( ToolBarManager aTbManager ) {
     Action fooAct = new Action( "My dropdown button", IAction.AS_DROP_DOWN_MENU ) {

        @Override
        public void run() {
           // TODO how to invoke button's dropdown menu?
        }

        @Override
        public void runWithEvent( Event event ) {
           // TODO how to invoke button's dropdown menu?
        }
     };
     aTbManager.add( fooAct );
  }

}
```

Comment: @greg-449 I'm not calling action from action. Anyway I need to show dropdown menu so how does any e4 service can help me?

Comment: If you can find an existing toolbar button in Eclipse that works like that it should be possible to read the source to see how it goes about it, but I can't see one.